# jquery to print from a modal window

Tags: jquery, printing

I have couple modal windows and I am trying to add "print this" functionality. I found a script and I am trying to modify this. He creates an iframe, loads the html, prints and then closes the frame. I am going to insert my ajax html response to that div. For some reason, my ajax response is not loading into the div that I want to print. This is what I have:

```
 // Create a jquery plugin that prints the given element.
jQuery.fn.print = function(){
// NOTE: We are trimming the jQuery collection down to the
// first element in the collection.
if (this.size() > 1){
    this.eq( 0 ).print();
    return;
} else if (!this.size()){
    return;
}

// ASSERT: At this point, we know that the current jQuery
// collection (as defined by THIS), contains only one
// printable element.

// Create a random name for the print frame.
var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());

// Create an iFrame with the new name.
var jFrame = $( "<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'>" );

// Hide the frame (sort of) and attach to the body.
jFrame
    .css( "width", "1px" )
    .css( "height", "1px" )
    .css( "position", "absolute" )
    .css( "left", "-9999px" )
    .appendTo( $( "body:first" ) )
;

// Get a FRAMES reference to the new frame.
var objFrame = window.frames[ strFrameName ];

// Get a reference to the DOM in the new frame.
var objDoc = objFrame.document;

// Write the HTML for the document. In this, we will
// write out the HTML of the current element.
objDoc.open();
objDoc.write( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">" );
objDoc.write( "<html>" );
objDoc.write( "<body>" );
objDoc.write( "<head>" );
objDoc.write( "<title>" );
objDoc.write( document.title );
objDoc.write( "</title>" );
objDoc.write( "<div id='viewNotes'></div>" );
objDoc.write( "</head>" );
//objDoc.write( this.html() );
objDoc.write( "</body>" );
objDoc.write( "</html>" );
//objDoc.close();

formData = 'cmid=C93F52DCE21ABBD5';
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/ajax_get_notes.cfm',
    type: 'GET',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $('#viewNotes').html(result);
    },
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
        $('#viewNotes').html('error:'+err);
    }
});     

// Print the document.
objFrame.focus();
//objFrame.print();

// Have the frame remove itself in about a minute so that
// we don't build up too many of these frames.
setTimeout(
    function(){
        jFrame.remove();
    },
    (60 * 1000)
    );

alert('i am here');
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things wrong.

First, the iFrame is not created because there is no closing tag.  Second, the iFrame is never added to the page.  Third, the jFrame CSS is not declared correctly (should be '#jframe').  Fourth, the html tags are in the wrong order.

I think you can go with something like this:

```
var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());

// Create an iFrame with the new name.
var jFrame = $( "<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'><div id='viewNotes'></div></iframe>" );

// Get a FRAMES reference to the new frame.
var objFrame = window.frames[ strFrameName ];

// Get a reference to the DOM in the new frame.
var objDoc = objFrame.document;

// Write the HTML for the document. In this, we will
// write out the HTML of the current element.
objDoc.open();
objDoc.write( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">" );
objDoc.write( "<html>" );
objDoc.write( "<head>" );
objDoc.write( "<title>" );
objDoc.write( document.title );
objDoc.write( "</title>" );
objDoc.write( "</head>" );
objDoc.write( "<body>" );
objDoc.write( jframe );
objDoc.write( "</body>" );
objDoc.write( "</html>" );
//objDoc.close();

formData = 'cmid=C93F52DCE21ABBD5';
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax/ajax_get_notes.cfm',
   type: 'GET',
   data: formData,
   cache: false,
   success: function(result) {
       $('#viewNotes').html(result);
   },
   error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
       $('#viewNotes').html('error:'+err);
   }
});     
//print
```

Comment: hi dave. thanks for your response but i am getting a :objFrame is undefined error in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing something different. I created another page called printNotes.cfm, which resembles the notes modal window. I attached a window.open event to a "printable version" button in the modal window. When clicked, this launches printNotes.cfm and this page loads the notes via ajax. In printNotes.cfm, there is a printer button and triggers window.print() event once clicked.

It works like a charm.

thanks